# Are Martial Artists armed (i.e. get +2 against unarmed foes)?

Tags: savage-worlds

Characters with the *Martial Artist* edge are not considered unarmed, which means that other armed characters do *not* get a +2 on their Fighting roll as per the Unarmed Defender rule (SWD, p76).

However, are they considered armed so that they do get that +2 bonus against other unarmed characters? Neither the *Martial Artist* nor the *Improved Martial Artist* (SWD, p36) make any mention about this.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes

Although it is not clear in the Savage World Deluxe writing, [it was confirmed by Clint on the official forums](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37722):

> [the rules say...] "He is never considered unarmed in combat" which
>   therefore would mean the opposite, that he is considered armed is
>   true. So yeah, **he would get the bonus**.

Comment: Good self answer.