# Two fisted and Wing Chun martial artist, Is the 3rd attack free?

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded

If a Two-Fisted Martial Artist has Wing Chun he gets his base attacks plus an additional attack. Does then third attack from Win Chun have any penalties?

Wing Chun:

> **Wing Chun**
>   *Requirements: Novice, Arcane Background
>   (Chi Mastery), Martial Arts,
>   Spirit d6+, Fighting d8+*
>   This style emphasizes flurries of powerful blows, usually both offensive and defensive at the same time. As long as your hero is attacking unarmed, he may make one additional Fighting attack at no penalty.
>    - *Deadlands Reloaded Player’s Guide - p.93*

and Two-Fisted:

> **Two Fisted**
>   *Requirements: Novice, Agility d8+*
>   A Two-Fisted hero isn’t ambidextrous—he’s simply learned to
>   fight with two weapons (or both fists) at once. When attacking
>   with a weapon in each hand, he rolls each attack separately
>   but ignores the multi-action penalty.
>   *- Savage Worlds Deluxe Explorer's Edition - p.40*

[In my memories](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27957/are-martial-artists-armed-i-e-get-2-against-unarmed-foes) Martial artist are armed even with no weapon. So Two fisted should apply.

Ps: I believe the penalty from the fff-hand attack should be negated by Wing Chun as the attack pattern is is:
 Main Hand (normal attack) >> off-hand (Free of what ever malus Wing Chun)>> Main Hand (two fisted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wing Chun gives you an extra attack with no penalty. The no penalty bit means exactly that, and there is no malus attached to it at all. Combining it with Two-Fisted gives you three attacks in total, one of which gets the off-hand penalty.

Effectively, you treat the two Edges seperately and they don't interact at all. Two-Fisted means you can make your two normal attacks without a Multiple Action Penalty, but one of those is with your off-hand. Wing Chun gives you an additional attack on top of that with no penalty at all.

See [here](http://www.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=27519&p=279255&hilit=wing%20chun#p279255) for official confirmation of this ruling.

Comment: I was tying to put the  Two-Fisted back on the main hand. but i guess they saw it comming. If i add a taunt in 4th action. it's -2 or -8 ? or you want me to make an other question? the amouth of dices looks awsome!

Comment: I'd ask that as a separate question